# UITableViewCell Reuse Cell Repeated Values

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm having a classic problem with the reuse of a `UITableViewCell`. I know what the problem is, but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong or how to fix it. When the screen first renders, everything looks great. But as the user scrolls, the same image and text displays repeatedly in sets of 8 rows.

Towards the end of the method, I print out the text value that is supposed to be displayed. This value looks great, as does the indexPath.row value. I just can't get the cells to be reused correctly.

I've left off the image refresh code, since it is little complex and not really relevant to the main issue. Please focus on the text updating, and I'm sure that the image updating will follow a similar pattern.

I think that I am setting up the cells correctly. Each subview is only added inside the `cell==nil` block. Then, I attempt to change the text outside of this block. But somehow it's not getting the correct pointer reference??? I'm stuck.

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    MyObject *obj = [self.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UILabel *name;
    UIImageView *imgView;

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        name = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        name.frame = CGRectMake(40, 0.0, _tableView.frame.size.width-40, 44);
        name.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        name.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5;
        [cell addSubview:name];

        imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 4, 36, 36);
        imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"];
        [imgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        [cell addSubview:imgView];
    }

    // this has to be outside the `cell == nil` block, right???        
    name.text = obj.name;

    // this output is perfect - but the actual cells are repeated!
    NSLog(@"indexpath: %d", indexPath.row);
    NSLog(@"name from array: %@", obj.name);

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Write your image and name create and assign value code below f (cell == nil) {} not between bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> // this has to be outside the `cell == nil` block, right???
>      name.text = obj.name;

It's incorrect. When the cell is not nil, the name label & image view are not alloced at all. If u persist to do like this, there's indeed a way can solve your issue (**using view tag**):

```
UILabel *name;
UIImageView *imgView;
NSInteger nameTag    = 101;
NSInteger imgViewTag = 102;

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    name = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    name.tag = nameTag;
    ...
    [cell addSubview:name];

    imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    imgView.tag = imgViewTag;
    ...
    [cell addSubview:imgView];
}
else {
  name    = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:nameTag];
  imgView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:imgViewTag];
}

name.text = obj.name;
...
```

---

#### BUT

I think you don't need to create new label & image view for the cell, there's `imageView` & `textLabel` available for the UITableViewCell. You can just update their value like this:

```
if (cell == nil) {
  // ...
}

cell.textLabel.text  = obj.name;
cell.imageView.image = obj.image;
```

---

And if u want to relayout the textLabel & imageView, u can create a subclass inherit from UITableViewCell, and override the `-layoutSubviews`:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
  [super layoutSubviews];

  // modify textLabel & imageView's frame
}
```

Comment: Great explanation. I could see that my references were nil upon reuse, but I couldn't figure out how to get a reference to them. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Randall glad to help u to figure it out ;)

Comment: Since iOS 6, the above pattern has been actively discouraged. Use cell prototypes or register NIB or subclass. Use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` rather than `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`. And we don't use cryptic `tag` values to identify subview anymore.

Comment: @Rob right, it's discouraged, that's why i said _"If u persist to do like this"_, it's main point is to explain the incorrect logic in his code. Thx for ur good note here :)

Answer (score 3):

As written, the `name` and `imgView` values will be `nil` for reused cells.

You need an `else` added to your `if` statement to set `name` and `imgView` by accessing the existing views from the cell.